# Dead Rising Prestige Point rewards

Tags: dead-rising

When leveling up in Dead Rising, you are rewarded with a new skill or a stat boost. Where can I find a list of all these rewards?

[DR wiki](http://deadrising.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Rising_Prestige_Points) ("leveling up list") is incomplete:

[image]

Comment: Is this list specific to a certain Dead Rising?  Or all of them?

Comment: I think this is specific to the first Dead Rising

Comment: @Mumford451: The original game, I have tagged the question.

Answer (score 1):

Each level will increase the following:

- Life;
- Attack Strength;
- Inventory Space;
- Throwing Distance;
- Speed.

You will also unlock skills.  The exact level that such skills unlock will vary for each save but fall within these ranges:

2-5:

- Jump Kick
- Zombie Ride

6-10:

- Flying Dodge
- Kick Back

11-15:

- Football Tackle
- Power Push

16-20:

- Judo Throw
- Double Lariat

21-25:

- Lift Up
- Roundhouse Kick

26-30:

- Knee Drop
- Suplex

31-35:

- Hammer Throw
- Wall Kick

36-40:

- Giant Swing
- Face Crusher
- Neck Twist

41-45:

- Disembowel
- Karate Chop
- Somersault Kick

50:

- Zombie Walk

---

Sources:

- [Skills](http://deadrising.wikia.com/wiki/Skills)
- [Prestige Points](http://deadrising.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Rising_Prestige_Points)